# how to update changes made to jqgrid using inline edit?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

how can we update the changes made to a cells of a particular row in the jqgrid....i want to update it to the database...im using inline edit for editing..i want to update that particular row to database where the usermade changes

this is my jquery code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var lastsel;
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '/Home/GetStudents/',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['StudentID', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Email'],
            colModel: [
      { name: 'StudentID',sortable: false,key:true },
      { name: 'FirstName' },
      { name: 'LastName', sortable: false},
      { name: 'Email', width: 200,  sortable: false}],
      cmTemplate: {align: 'center', editable: true},
            pager: '#pager',
            width: 750,
            rowNum: 15,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'StudentID',
            sortorder: "asc",
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: ' My First JQgrid',
            onSelectRow: function (StudentID) {


                if (StudentID != lastsel) {


                    jQuery('#list').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
                    jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editRow', StudentID, true);

                    lastsel = StudentID;   
                }

            },

            editurl: '/Home/About/',
            caption: "Using events example"

        });
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', "#pager", { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check following sample project:

- [jqGrid in ASP.NET MVC 3 and Razor](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/61796)

It contains (among many others) sample for inline editing scenario.

Comment: im facing problem while running that application, with connection string and i have no idea about that tables sturucture used for that application, so the data is not loading nd its giving error

Comment: @beingfab As the description for project informs, you need to download and install [Northwind Database](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23654), then change your the connection string to point it.

Comment: @beingfab Northwind Database contains all the tables and data that application is using - you just need to install it.